# Change caption number of an algorithm

Tags: numbering, captions, algorithms

I am wondering if I can manually set the caption number of an algorithm, or let the caption number of the algorithms in an article start from 2. The following is a MWE.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
%\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\algnewcommand{\LineComment}[1]{\State \(\triangleright\) #1}

\begin{document}

%\title{xxx}
%
%\maketitle

\alglanguage{pseudocode}
\begin{algorithm}[h]
\large
\caption{\large Insert into CBF}
\label{Algorithm:insert}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Procedure{$\mathbf{InsertItem}$}{item $x$}
    \LineComment{\emph{First insert $x$ into CBF}}
    \For {$i = 1 \to k$}
            \State $C_{f_i(x)\%N}$ ++
    \EndFor
\EndProcedure
\Statex
\end{algorithmic}
  \vspace{-0.4cm}%
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This just amounts to adding

```
\setcounter{algorithm}{1}
```

just before `\begin{algorithm}` (one less than the desired number).

***Notes.***

1. Your usage of `\large` is dubious. If you're using `IEEEtran`, then probably you're submitting a paper. Don't add formatting instructions like `\large`, because this will go against uniformity of the papers in the proceedings volume where the paper will appear. Also, with `\large` in the argument to `\caption` only the text and not the label will be in `\large` size.
2. Say `\usepackage{mathptmx}` rather than `\usepackage{times}`, or the math will be in Computer Modern which is visually incompatible with Times. But, if Times is a requirement of the class, it will be automatically chosen by it. Again, if this is a submission, don't add formatting instructions like this.
3. `hyperref` should be called last.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. In fact, I am indeed to submit a paper. For your notes, I have some questions. 1) If I cannot use \large or \small, how can I change the fonts in the algorithm? 2) The MWE in this question is only for this website, in fact I am using `\usepackage{mathrsfs}` and  `\usepackage{amsmath}`. Will these two packages work fine? I know little about what you metioned. 3) This is only a submission, I will call `hyperref ` if the paper is accepted.

Comment: You should not change any fontsizes, that is up to the journal to decide, not the author. (2) They will work fine. Regarding `Times font`, only add it if requested by the journal. You will save a lot of the journals time by not messing with layout, fonts, margins etc.

Comment: It seems that after setting the counter, the reference number does not change. For example, if the algorithm is labeled as \label{alg}, then \ref{alg} still displays 1 rather than 3. How to solve this problem?

Comment: @zbh2047 The `\label` must go inside `\caption` or after it.

Answer (score 3):

You can manually change the counter associated to the `algorithm` environment with:

```
\addtocounter{algorithm}{1}
```

Your code can be:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\algnewcommand{\LineComment}[1]{\State \(\triangleright\) #1}
\begin{document}

\addtocounter{algorithm}{1}
\alglanguage{pseudocode}
\begin{algorithm}[h]
\large
\caption{\large Insert into CBF}
\label{Algorithm:insert}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Procedure{$\mathbf{InsertItem}$}{item $x$}
  \LineComment{\emph{First insert $x$ into CBF}}
  \For {$i = 1 \to k$}
        \State $C_{f_i(x)\%N}$ ++
\EndFor
\EndProcedure
 \Statex
\end{algorithmic}
\vspace{-0.4cm}%
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you, it works. I have voted for you, but egreg offered an answer earlier than you, so I cannot accept your answer as the solution.

Comment: Don't worry, egreg answer is more complete than mine.

Answer (score 1):

```
\renewcommand{\thealgorithm}{3.\arabic{algorithm}}
\setcounter{algorithm}{0}
```

The above command will rename it to Algorithm 3.1 and so on.

If you want, may delete the `\arabic{algorithm}` command to have it as algorithm 3.