# How to put a custom tag to the algorithm environment?

Tags: numbering, algorithms

I am trying a way to number algorithms 1a, 1b, 1c, 2a, 2b, 2c, etc. As I understand from the documentation of the `algorithms` package [here](http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/algorithms/algorithms.pdf), I can number them after the part, chapter, section and so on. In [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118632/change-caption-number-of-an-algorithm) related topic they discuss how to customize the number. But I don't want the number, I would like to also have letters: for example, in the following MWE, I would like to have the two algorithms numbered (and therefore referenced to as) 1a and 1b.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\begin{document}
Algorithm~\ref{MyAlg} does things in a way. Algorithm~\ref{MyOtherAlg} does things in some other way.
\begin{algorithm}\caption{My algorithm}\label{MyAlg}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\State Do stuff.
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\begin{algorithm}\caption{My other algorithm}\label{MyOtherAlg}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\State Do stuff differently.
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Any idea on how to achieve this?

Comment: And what represents the "1"? Is it associated to a section?

Comment: no, it can be a custom number

Comment: What is a sequential counter? A user-defined one?

Comment: See my edit: a custom number. It might as well not be there. For example I may want to number them simply "A" and "B", let's say. Hand curated numbering.

Comment: Please see my recently updated answer. Something like that (see the las to examples after "Update")?

Comment: Kind of your first update (with the user-defined counter), but let's say after 1a and 1b, I want to decide to pass to 2a and 2b. I believe that since the sequence of numbers and letters in the numbering is not related to chapters and sections, I have to reset and increment these counters manually, right?

Comment: Yes. You need to use `\refstepcounter{mycount}` to increase the defined counter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do is to redefine the command `\thealgorithm` which controls the representation for the algorithm counter. For example, to number them using alphabetic lower-case characters and to prepend the section number you would do

```
\renewcommand\thealgorithm{\thesection\alph{algorithm}}
```

Assuming that you want the counter to reset at every section, you will also need

```
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{algorithm}{section}
```

A complete example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{chngcntr}

\counterwithin{algorithm}{section}
\renewcommand\thealgorithm{\thesection\alph{algorithm}}

\begin{document}
\section{Test section}

Algorithm~\ref{MyAlg} does things in a way. Algorithm~\ref{MyOtherAlg} does things in some other way.
\begin{algorithm}\caption{My algorithm}\label{MyAlg}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\State Do stuff.
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\begin{algorithm}\caption{My other algorithm}\label{MyOtherAlg}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\State Do stuff differently.
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

### Update:

Same idea if a user-defined counter is to be used:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{chngcntr}

\newcounter{mycount}
\counterwithin{algorithm}{mycount}
\refstepcounter{mycount}
\renewcommand\thealgorithm{\arabic{mycount}\alph{algorithm}}

\begin{document}
\section{Test section}

Algorithm~\ref{MyAlg} does things in a way. Algorithm~\ref{MyOtherAlg} does things in some other way.
\begin{algorithm}\caption{My algorithm}\label{MyAlg}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\State Do stuff.
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\begin{algorithm}\caption{My other algorithm}\label{MyOtherAlg}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\State Do stuff differently.
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

or to have the numbering with upper-case alphabetical characters:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\renewcommand\thealgorithm{\Alph{algorithm}}

\begin{document}
\section{Test section}

Algorithm~\ref{MyAlg} does things in a way. Algorithm~\ref{MyOtherAlg} does things in some other way.
\begin{algorithm}\caption{My algorithm}\label{MyAlg}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\State Do stuff.
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\begin{algorithm}\caption{My other algorithm}\label{MyOtherAlg}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\State Do stuff differently.
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Can we do something like this: For 2 algorithms Algorithm 2(a) and Algorithm 2(b) and the rest of the Algorithms like   Algorithm 1, Algorithm 3, etc follow the normal naming and numbering styles?