# How can I put a period right after the algorithm's number in the algorithm's title?

Tags: algorithms

[image]

I wish it said "Algorithm 1.", with a period after the number, and not just "Algorithm 1".  It's how I see most people using it, so I must be using an unconventional package?  Would you say I should stick to the default?  It's not ugly.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Some random algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}[0]
\Procedure{random}{}:
\EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`caption`](//ctan.org/pkg/caption) to change the `labelsep` method to `period`. Since the original caption sets the algorithm label in **bold**, we also change `labelfont` to `bf`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm,caption}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\captionsetup[algorithm]{
  labelfont = bf,
  labelsep = period
}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Some random algorithm}
  \begin{algorithmic}[0]
    \Procedure{random}{}
    \EndProcedure
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

The usual way seems to work. (See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/250999/121799) for further examples.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand\thealgorithm{\arabic{algorithm}.}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Some random algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}[0]
\Procedure{random}{}:
\EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: While this works in terms of the presentation you'll see an issue when you use `\label`-`\ref`. The period will carry to `\ref`.

Comment: @Werner It depends on what the OP wants. And it is no problem to remove the period, as you probably know. And if you really think it is a reason for concern, make the comment under [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/250999/121799).

Comment: Everything depends on what the OP wants. And the main principle is to insert the period, not remove it. Why reference Gonzalo's answer?

Comment: @Werner Because in Gonzalo's answer the same trick is used.

Comment: His answer correctly applies changes to the counter representation because it only contains numbers, not punctuation. Same "trick," but a correct application.

Comment: @Werner My application is certainly not "incorrect".

Comment: Correct. It provides unwanted side-effects in a typical use-case.

Comment: @Werner I f you were as picky when it comes to your own answers, then such comments would not leave this bitter after-taste.

Comment: You're welcome to comment on my answers and shouldn't consider constructive criticism as a personal attack.

Comment: @Werner I prefer different kinds of interactions and behavior. This includes giving proper credit earlier posts, and constructive wording for constructive comments. As this is a matter of taste, we will probably not reach an agreement here.

Comment: I understand what you mean by "constructive wording for constructive comments," but don't see how this applies here. [Give proper credit](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7940/5764), good. I don't see how this applies here.