# Can't modify algorithm2e caption numbering

Tags: captions, numbering, algorithm2e

I want to change the numbering of one algorithm from Algorithm 5 to Algorithm 2.1.

I've tried all these methods:

[Change caption number of an algorithm](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118632/change-caption-number-of-an-algorithm)

https://github.com/hadizadeh/Latex_algorithm

No matter how I modify the code, the result is always the same. Here is an example.

```
\usepackage[ruled, vlined, linesnumbered, nofillcomment]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

...

\begin{algorithm}[H]
    \renewcommand{\thealgorithm}{2.1}
    \caption{Name of the algorithm}
    test1\\
    test2
\end{algorithm}
```

[image]

It doesn't matter if I put `\renewcommand{\thealgorithm}{2.1}` inside or outside the algorithm environment.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will make algorithm number be **section number . algorithm number**

[image: a]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[ruled, vlined, linesnumbered, nofillcomment]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

%****************************************** added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\fnum@algocf}{\AlCapSty{\AlCapFnt\algorithmcfname\nobreakspace\thesection.\thealgocf}}%
\makeatother
%******************************************

\begin{document}
    
    \setcounter{section}{3}% test section numbers   
    \setcounter{algocf}{5}% test algo numbers
        
    \section{A section} 
    
    \begin{algorithm}
        \caption{Name of the algorithm}
        test1\\
        test2
    \end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

The caption separator can be controlled using `\SetAlgoCaptionSeparator{sep}` (default `:`)

If you want to reset the algorithm counter at the beginning of a section add to the preamble

```
\let\oldsection\section
\renewcommand{\section}{\setcounter{algocf}{0}\oldsection}
```

**OPTION**

This is another option using the `dcounter` package, using the section number and also will reset the algorithm counter starting a new section of so desired.

[image: d]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[ruled, vlined, linesnumbered, nofillcomment]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

 \SetAlgoCaptionSeparator{} % default :

\usepackage{dcounter} % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\countstyle{section}%
\DeclareDynamicCounter{algocf}%  reset the algorithm counter starting a new section
 
\begin{document}
    
    \setcounter{section}{3}% test section numbers   
                
    \section{A section} 
    
    \begin{algorithm}
        \caption{Name of the algorithm 1}
        test1\\
        test2
    \end{algorithm}

    \begin{algorithm}
        \caption{Name of the algorithm 2}
        test1\\
        test2
    \end{algorithm}
    
    \section{Another section}   
    
    \begin{algorithm}
        \caption{Name of the algorithm 3}
        test1\\
        test2
    \end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```